# Finding adb accelerometer events on Android mobile

Tags: android, automation, adb

I would like to find android accelerometer events produced from a real device while shaking it. I use **adb shell getevent** command but there is no any accelerometer related event during shake mobile action. The only events are:

```
$ getevent

add device 1: /dev/input/event5, name:     "certify_hall"

add device 2: /dev/input/event6, name:     "ssp_context"

could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter

could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter

add device 3: /dev/input/event1, name:     "sec_touchscreen"

add device 4: /dev/input/event3, name:     "gpio_keys"

add device 5: /dev/input/event0, name:     "sec_touchkey"

add device 6: /dev/input/event4, name:     "hall"

add device 7: /dev/input/event2, name:     "Codec3026 Headset Events"


$ ls /dev/input/

event0 event1 event2 event3 event4 event5 event6 mice mouse0
```

I  mention that the mobile phone that I am testing is not rooted. Furthermore, accelerometer is already enabled and working fine (tested with other apps).

Is there any way I could use to find the accelerometer events? My intension is to find and reproduced them(using **adb shell sendevent** command) so as to simulate shake mobile real action.

Thanks in advance!